# Grep linux regular expression

Tags: html, regex, linux, bash, cut

Hi everyone I have an issue..

I'm trying to wrote regexp but I already have no suggestions..

I have some file with html source.

```
</tr>
    <tr anotherID="433943" sometext="">
    <td>
    .a lot of source
    .a lot of source
    .a lot of source
    .a lot of source
    .a lot of source
    </tr>
    <tr WANTED_ID="361112" sometext="">
    <td>
    <some title text or anything></span>
    </td>
    <td>
    thisisnamewhichInow
    .a lot of source
    .a lot of source
    .a lot of source
    .a lot of source
    .a lot of source
```

So. I want to paste WANDED_ID into my variable. But I know only "thisisnamewhichInow".. I can use any utility in bash. example 'cut'.

Comment: `I want to paste WANDED_ID into my variable`, which variable? Did you want to get the value of WANDED_ID?

Comment: Yes. I want do this in my script: myvariable=$(grep 'someregex' filewithsource);
But I don't know which regex use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get you what you want, the last id before your known string

```
myvariable=$(perl -e'$/=undef;<>=~/.*id="(\d+)".*?bgMiner.vminer/s;print"$1\n"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below grep command to get the value of `WANDED_ID`,

```
myvariable=$(grep -oP 'WANTED_ID="\K[^"]+' filewithsource)
```

Comment: Yes it's working but only for this source. :)
It's my fault, I forget tell anotherID and WANTED_ID in my source will have the same name ->> "id" I wrote another because I wanted to show which I need to draw

Comment: please post the exact input.. Which id value you want?

Comment: Yes, sorry. http://pastebin.com/qQLUa5Pz Here is the full source. I try to draw id 361112 but I know only 'bgMiner.vminer' string.

Answer (score 0):

using cut

```
    my_var=`grep WANTED_ID filewithsource|cut -f 2 -d "\""`
```